# How to convert one type of list with objects to another?

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to convert a list of a particular type of an object to another. Here is the original type;

```
 public class OriginialType
 {
    public string Module { get; set; }
    public string Screen { get; set; }
    public string Permission { get; set; }
 }
```

And here is the list of this target type;

```
List<OriginialType> orignialList = new List<OriginialType>();
orignialList.Add(new OriginialType { Module = "Module1", Screen = "Dashboard", Permission = "Add" });
orignialList.Add(new OriginialType { Module = "Module1", Screen = "Dashboard", Permission = "Edit" });
orignialList.Add(new OriginialType { Module = "Module1", Screen = "Dashboard", Permission = "Delete" });
```

Here is the target type I want a list of;

```
public class TargetType
{
    public string Module { get; set; }
    public List<Screen> Screen { get; set; }
}

public class Screen
{
    public string ScreenName { get; set; }
    public string Permission { get; set; }
}
```

So instead of having a list that has items containing the same module repeatedly, I want a list that stores a module once while having all the screens associated with it. How can I convert this OriginalType into my TargetType?

**Edit**:The solution by @itsme86 worked perfectly. But I realized I needed the name of the screens to show up once too. So modified his solution a bit. First changed my TargetType to;

```
public class TargetType
{
    public string Module { get; set; }
    public List<Screen> Screen { get; set; }
}

public class Screen
{
    public string ScreenName { get; set; }
    public List<Permission> Permission { get; set; }
}

public class Permission
{
    public string PermissionName { get; set; }
}
```

And the whole conversion method to;

```
 foreach (var grouping in roleRightsList.GroupBy(o => new { o.Module, o.Screen }))
        {
            TargetModel target = new TargetModel { Module = grouping.Key.Module };
            targetList.Add(target);

            Screen targetScreen = new Screen { ScreenName = grouping.Key.Screen };
            targetScreen.Permission = grouping.Select(o => new Permission
            {
                PermissionName = o.Permission,
            }).ToList();

            target.Screen = new List<Screen>();
            target.Screen.Add(targetScreen);
        }
```

Appreciate all the answers.

Comment: What have you tried to do so far, and what problems have you had implementing your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do something simple like this:

```
List<TargetType> targetList = new List<TargetList>();

foreach (var grouping in originalList.GroupBy(o => o.Module))
{
    TargetType target = new TargetType { Module = grouping.Key };
    targetList.Add(target);
    target.Screen = grouping.Select(o => new Screen
       {
          ScreenName = o.Screen,
          Permission = o.Permission
       }).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var targetTypes = orignialList.GroupBy(o => o.Module)
    .Select(
        g =>
            new TargetType
            {
                Module = g.Key,
                Screen =
                    g.Select(t => new Screen {Permission = t.Permission, ScreenName = t.Screen}).ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

..a bit more explicit here:

```
List<TargetType> targetTypeList = new List<TargetType>();
List<IGrouping<string, OriginialType>> grouping = orignialList.GroupBy(o => o.Module).ToList();

foreach(IGrouping<string, OriginialType> group in grouping)
{
    TargetType newItem = new TargetType() { Module = group.Key, Screen = new List<Screen>() };                

    foreach(OriginialType o in group)
        newItem.Screen.Add(new Screen() { ScreenName = o.Screen, Permission = o.Permission });   

    targetTypeList.Add(newItem);
}
```